# How to make a back button using http_referer in Smarty template for internal links only

Tags: php, smarty, http-referer

I am using the following code on my website to make a Back button in Smarty template:

```
<div id="back-button">
<a href="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER}">BACK</a>
```

This works as needed when navigating through internal pages. But, when a user visits my website via a hyperlink on external website, the back button redirects him to that external site.  I want the button to work only if http_referer value is an internal link. As for the external links, it should redirect to the homepage of my website.

Sorry if you my question is extremely easy. I am new to Smarty.

P.S. I know how to make it in Javascript. I need it using smarty.

Thanks

Comment: http referer is set by the requesting server when it asks for any resource, be it internal or external. What you can do is to get this value server side in your code and place in internal variable. Then use the variable as per need within the hyperlink

Comment: You should check the domain before setting up the referrer. If the link matches the HOST than set the HTTP_REFERER

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Please can you share a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
{if isset($smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER) && strpos($smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER, $smarty.server.HTTP_HOST) != false}
  <a href="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER}">Back</a>
{else}
  <a href="/">Back</a>
{/if}
```

it checks if a referer exists and is from the same host and then add a referrer link if not it add a homepage link

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This line `{$link->getPageLink('index')}` produced an error. So I have corrected it and did some improvements.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `{if isset($smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER) && stripos($smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER, $smarty.server.SERVER_NAME) != false}
  <a href="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER}">Back</a>
{else}
  <a href="/">Back</a>
{/if}`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't look that this question related only with smarty and used that part from prestashop. I'll fix it